# why do you need console.writeLine(), to call a method? (Beginner)

Tags: c#

So basically, while studying, I was asked to create a method, which takes two arguments  and returns the answer. so what I did was this:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
      sum(5,3);
    }
    
    static int sum(int x, int y){
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

But when I asked them to check it, they said it was wrong and that the correct answer should be like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
      Console.WriteLine(sum(5,3));
    }
    
    static int sum(int x, int y){
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

So I wanted to understand why we have to use "Console.WriteLine()" to print out the value, because I remember in a previous lesson that a method can be called by just using the name of the method followed by parenthesis, just like in the first code block.

Comment: Both is true: you can perfectly call the method by using just `sum(5,3)` but you will see nothing printed on the console. If you want to see the result, you have to do `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: Console.WriteLine() is used to print the result on console window so that user can see the result. If you will not use this then how end user will see the result of sum method.

Comment: What you did was absolutely correct. You just can't see the result.

Comment: return != print to console. return = return value to the calling method.

Comment: You _can_ call a method that returns something, so which is not a `void` method, without using the returned value. But it doesn't make much sense to calculate a value if you don't do anything with it. `Console.WriteLine(sum(5,3))` prints the result to the console, so it consumes the expression.

Comment: oh yes, now I get it, thank you very much for the support

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct. However, your program is not useful. For a program to be useful, it should display something to the user, or have some kind of tangible side effect when it is executed.

While your program does indeed calculate the sum of two numbers, it doesn't do anything with that information. The method doing the calculation does return the result, but once execution returns to the `Main()` method, you've provided no instructions as to what should happen next.

That's where `Console.WriteLine()` comes in. You don't need `Console.Writeline()` to call a method. `Console.Writeline()` is a predefined method that takes some input and writes it to the console. In other words, it makes something visible to the user. So the reason you're being asked to use it, is because they want the result to be visible in the user interface, and since this is a console application, the user interface is the console.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Console.Write to call a method but to print a value. I modified your code and as you see I am calling the method without Console.Write and using Console.Write just for printing the result.

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int result = sum(5, 3);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    static int sum(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```